# Private API Gateway behind load balancer target group shows unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-security-group, amazon-elb

I'm trying to put an endpoint attached to a private API gateway behind a load balancer as explained in the following article so that I can use custom DNS with the private API gateway.

https://georgemao.medium.com/enabling-private-apis-with-custom-domain-names-aws-api-gateway-df1b62b0ba7c

It's all set up the way he explains it but the problem is that the health checks from the target group are failing. The health checks are set to accept response codes from 200-499(a troubleshooting measure).

I can attempt to access the the endpoint IP from the VPC and get a 403 but it doesn't seem to respond from the load balancer. The target group health checks are set to check https on the traffic port but they are all timing out. This is some sort of reachability issue but I can't figure out why I can reach it but the load balancer cannot. The security group I have applied right now allows traffic from 0/0 on port 443 inbound.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

As you mentionned, your ALB's security group inbound rules are ok.

Now check the **outbound rules**, and verify the traffic on port 443 is allowed too.

### Explanation

If it's not the case, the healthchecks are waiting for a response from the VPC endpoint, which is blocked by the Load Balancer's security group outbound rules.

And so the healthcheck is still waiting for a response which never comes. That explains the 504 timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, i add an **outbound** rule in the Load Balancer's security group, port 443 with cidr block of the private subtnet as destination.
Make sure you have the ALB and VPC endpoint in the same Az.

Answer (score -1):

Heyy, I have exactly the same issue, the reachability analyzer confirm the connection between the vpc endpoint eni and alb eni but health check still unhealthy

Comment: More suited as a comment

Comment: Hicham - Did you figure it out? I ended up moving the LB and the endpoint into the same subnet and that fixed it.

Comment: Yes I had a problem with target groups seems it's not working with HTTP protocol but HTTPS. Thank youu for asking :)

Comment: changing the health check protocol from http to https port 443 worked.